# TransformationFailedException when entity is passed to Form

Tags: php, forms, symfony, validation, entity

I'm using Symfony 3.3 and im getting this TransformationFailedException Error, when i load my profile page:

> Unable to transform value for property path "postalcode": Expected a numeric.

The postalcode value for this user in the database is:

> '34125abc'

The postalcode attribute defined in UserProfile Entity:

```
/**
 * @ORM\Column(type="string")
 */
 private $postalcode;
```

My ProfileController:

```
class ProfileController extends Controller{

    /**
     * @Route("/edit_profile", name="edit_profile")
     */
    public function profileAction(Request $request){

        $profile = $this->getDoctrine()->getManager()->getRepository('AppBundle:UserProfile')->findOneBy(['user_id' => $this->getUser()->getUserId()]);

        // If no UserProfile exists, create a UserProfile Object to insert it into database after POST
        if(null === $profile){
            $profile = new UserProfile();
            $profile->setUserId($this->getUser()->getUserId());
        }

        $form = $this->createForm(EditProfileFormType::class);
        $form->setData($profile);

        // only handles data on POST
        $form->handleRequest($request);

        if($form->isSubmitted() && $form->isValid()) {

            $result = $this->forward('AppBundle:API\User\Profile:update_profile', array(
                'profile'  => $profile
            ));

            if(200 === $result->getStatusCode()){
                $this->addFlash('success', "Profile successfully created!");
            }
        }

        return $this->render(':User/Profile:edit_profile.html.twig', [
            'EditProfileForm' => $form->createView(),
        ]);
    }
}
```

My EditProfileFormType:

```
class EditProfileFormType extends AbstractType
{
    public function buildForm(FormBuilderInterface $builder, array $options)
    {
        $builder
            ->add('title', ChoiceType::class, array(
                'choices' => array(
                    'Mr' => 'Mr',
                    'Mrs' => 'Mrs'
                )
            ))
            ->add('firstName')
            ->add('lastName')
            ->add('street')
            ->add('postalcode', NumberType::class)
            ->add('city')
            ->add('telephone')
            ->add('mobile')
            ->add('company')
            ->add('birthday' , BirthdayType::class)
            ->add('callback', CheckboxType::class);
    }

    public function configureOptions(OptionsResolver $resolver)
    {
        $resolver->setDefaults([
           'data_class' => 'AppBundle\Entity\UserProfile',
            'validation_groups' => array('edit_profile')
        ]);
    }

    public function getBlockPrefix()
    {
        return 'app_bundle_edit_profile_form_type';
    }
}
```

So the problem here seems to be the not numeric string value in the databse

> '34125abc'

which is stored in the `$profile` entity object and is passed to the form by `$form->setData($profile);` So when the data is being set, the error is thrown because of the Numbertype in this line `->add('postalcode', NumberType::class)`. Is there a way to pass the postalcode value to the form, even if it's not numeric and only check the Numbertype, when the form is submitted? Because i don't need validation, when I pass data to the form. Just when, it's submitted.

Comment: You can validate the postalcode in the controller, and remove the restriction from the form type class.

Comment: I would've to validate all my form fields in every controller. That's not worth it. Isn't there another way around? I would like to make the restrictions in the model instead of the form. But I get the same error then. In the model like this: `/**
     * @ORM\Column(type="string")
     * @Assert\Type(
     *     type="numeric",
     *     groups={"edit_profile"}
     * )
     */
    private $postalcode;`

Answer (score -1):

The solution was quite simple, but hard to find out.. I changed

> ->add('postalcode', NumberType::class)

to

> ->add('postalcode', TextType::class)

in my EditProfileFormType.php. 
Why? 
Because the form builder just need to know the type of the field in the database. It's shouldn't care in this case if it is numeric or not, because thats the task of the model restriction. In this case it is a **string**, so it is **Texttype** in a form. All the form type's are applied, when the form is set, but the validation groups are just validated, when the form is submitted! That's exactly they way it should be!